# Soldered RAM: is it possible to isolate just the damaged cells in way or another?

Tags: memory, hardware-failure

I have an Asus K550V notebook with Windows 10 Pro X64, bought few years ago and out of warranty. This model has 8GB DDR4 Ram module directly soldered on motherboard and also has a slot for adding other 8GB. The problem is that the soldered module has some damaged cells (as showed by Sysmark MemTest86 utility) and this, obviously, causes a lot of troubles (blue screens and so on) and it also makes impossible to reinstall Windows (or even Linux). I cannot afford neither to buy a new laptop just now nor an expensive repair and I absolutely need it for my job so I wonder: is there any chance to bypass the damaged cells so that an OS doesn’t use them and can work correctly something similar to, for example, the marked bad clusters makes by checkdisk?

Comment: No, in order to fix this, you need to get new RAM, unsolder the old RAM, and solder the new one back in place.

Comment: If you feel (really) adventurous, you can try the method depicted here (https://www.deskdecode.com/how-to-repair-a-dead-ram-stick-memory-stick/): it's not a joke, it does work, apparently, but you'll need to separate your RAM stick from the mobo first. Aside from that, as LPChip said, you need new RAM, and I'm pretty sure you can't just add a new, removable one into the empty slot, as the soldered module is in slot 0. If it's toast, juice won't flow through to the other stick, or badly.

Comment: On the other hand, I found this too: https://thecomputerperson.wordpress.com/2015/04/20/how-to-block-out-or-map-out-bad-ram-in-windows/

Comment: A specially designed driver like a most basic kernel mode driver may can demand a piece of physical RAM around that address. Then it will always be occupied by that driver and you ensure the driver get loaded eary during boot.

Comment: Not sure whether you can dig a PCI hole around that address which should also be digged by a kernel mode driver.

Comment: You should use hot air if you are going to attempt this. There a few pages (videos) on youtube.